# cout and printf show different results in displaying linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, printf, cout

I know the problem has been addressed a million times here, and I know it's about the typesafety (or rather lack of it) of printf, but I would like some help with the fix since the prof completely refuses C++ solutions.
I have the following structure:

```
struct node  
{  
        char author[40];  
        char title[40];  
        float price;  
        int stock;  
        nod *next;          
};
```

I know for a fact that the info is properly stored and I've narrowed the problem down to the displaying function:

```
void display()                      
{    
   nod *nod;    
   nod=p;                           
   while(nod)                       
   {    
      printf("%s \t %s \t %e \t%d", &node->auhtor, &node->title, &node->price, &node->stock);         
      node=node->next;}                
      printf("\n");    
   }    
}
```

What exactly do I need to change for it to display the same results as

```
cout<<nod->autor<<'\t'<<nod->titlu<<'\t'<<nod->pret<<'\t'<<nod->stoc<<endl;
```

Comment: Could you please post the output you got with each version? And state which difference you see?

Comment: You don't seem to have made up your mind about how to spell your variable names. That might be a start.

Comment: Invest in spaces around the `<<` operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove all the ampersands. You want the real deal, so don't apply the reference operator.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, remove the spaces before and after the tabs in the printf version.